# How to open a media file in the specified directory without adding the file to the project

Tags: c#, file, uwp, mediaelement

I want to open a file on a computer on a local network with its full directory. Something like that:

```
var path = "C:/User/Folder/video.mp4";
var stream = ...;
\\code
mediaElement.SetSource(stream,"");
```

I haven't found any ways on the internet. There were options only to add a file to the project, but this is not what I need.

Comment: Maybe FileWebRequest class will help you to get stream to the file on local network

Comment: Have you tried `StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path)` from the `Windows.Storage` namespace for using it in your `stream` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to open a media file in the specified directory without adding the file to the project

There are two ways to do it. **FileOpenPicker** and **broadFileSystemAccess**

**FileOpenPicker**

The first one is to use [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-22621). When you use it, it will show a window that lets the user choose and open files. It does not require any extra permissions but users need to know where the file is and pick the file by themself.

Code:

```
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        mediaPlayer.Play();
```

**broadFileSystemAccess**

The second one is to use the restricted capability called **broadFileSystemAccess**.  You need to add the capability into your app's manifestfile like this:

```
    <Package
...
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Then you could use APIs from [Windows.Storage Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage?view=winrt-22621) to get files directly via path. Like:

```
 StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\video.mp4");

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
        mediaPlayer.Play();
```

When you use this capability, please make sure that user has enabled the file system privacy setting after installed the app. You could find the settings in **Settings > Privacy > File system**.

[image]

Comment: I don't have such a drop-down list on windows 11.

Comment: @Chārry You need to install your app which added the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability first. Then the app will show in the Settings.